# How to attach a global variable that contains a function to a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, variables

I want to create a global variable that contains a function

```
var showSlider = function() {
    $('#slider-content').css("display","block");
    $('#slider-content').delay(1000).addClass('animated slideInRight');
}
```

How can I attach it to a click event?

```
$('a.shipping-btn').on("click", function(){
    $('#main-content').removeClass('span12');
    $('#main-content').addClass('span8');
    $(showSlider);
});
```

Comment: Like this `$(selector).on('click', showSlider);` ?

Comment: or change `$(showSlider);` to `showSlider();`

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you just invoke it?

```
$('a.shipping-btn').on("click", function(){
    $('#main-content').removeClass('span12');
    $('#main-content').addClass('span8');
    showSlider();
});
```

You don't need jQuery to perform basic JavaScript language tasks.

That said... doing `$(showSlider)` will work, but I can't imagine you'd need to do that in a click event, unless you think the click could happen before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I'm new to javascript/jquery so I'm learning on the fly.

Comment: @Julius: If you are new to JavaScript use [**Mozilla MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and for jQuery the [**jQuery documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/) as a resource. Learning on the fly is OK but you should probably use those resource in your spare time when ever possible so you have the basic fundamentals learned at least. I also found the book, "Javascript The Good Parts" very useful at the start.